# grayscale gradient with skimage or numpy

Tags: image-processing, numpy, scikit-image

I have to create a linear grayscale gradient, with black shade on top and white shade at the bottom. I have to use skimage and numpy.

I've found on scikit the code for a color linear gradient that goes horizontally instead of vertically here: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_tinting_grayscale_images.html.

I would like an explanation of this code and some hints on how put everything in grayscale and vertical instead of colored and horizontal. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A grey-scale image can be represented as a two-dimensional matrix.  Let's say we wanted to create a 100x100 gradient image.  First, we use `np.linspace` to construct the gradient values, 100 values between 0 and 1.  We then repeat this vector 100 times in the vertical direction (using `np.tile`) to form the gradient image.  At this stage, the image is a gradient from left to right, so we use the transpose to flip it to be oriented up-down.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
image = np.tile(x, (100, 1)).T

plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```